# apt-get install Python3 in fresh Ubuntu Docker Image results in Error 13 Permission Denied

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ubuntu, apt, failed-installation

**Update2**

Okay, I've rebuilt the Ubuntu server from scratch and the problem still exists.  This is how I am doing it.

1. Create a virtual machine in ESXI with two disk volumes.  The first is 50GB and the second is 250GB.
2. Run the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS install
3. Create a static IP address
4. Create two LVM volumes, the 50GB is root and the 350GB is mounted as /var
5. Select Docker and Prometheus to be installed along with Ubuntu
6. Let the install run to completion.
7. Unmount the CD rom when finished and reboot Ubuntu
8. Login and then sudo bash
9. docker pull ubuntu
10. docker run -it ubuntu
11. apt-get update
12. apt-get install -y python3

You should get the error

I am running a new/fresh Ubuntu Docker image on a 22.04 LTS Ubuntu server instance.  Docker was installed during the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS install.  It is a new Ubuntu 22.04 LTS install.

I'm using docker version 20.10.17, build 100c70180f.

I am having trouble getting python3 installed in the running docker container.

To start off, I get the Ubuntu image running in a container:

`docker run -ti ubuntu`

In the image I run (as the root user)

`apt update`

Then I run

`apt install python3`

The installation fails with:

```
root@6bfb4be344d6:/# apt-get install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libexpat1 libmpdec3 libpython3-stdlib libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libreadline8 libsqlite3-0 media-types python3-minimal python3.10 python3.10-minimal readline-common
Suggested packages:
  python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv python3.10-venv python3.10-doc binutils binfmt-support readline-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libexpat1 libmpdec3 libpython3-stdlib libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libreadline8 libsqlite3-0 media-types python3 python3-minimal python3.10 python3.10-minimal readline-common
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6494 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpython3.10-minimal amd64 3.10.6-1~22.04.2 [810 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libexpat1 amd64 2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2 [91.0 kB]                                                                                                              
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3.10-minimal amd64 3.10.6-1~22.04.2 [2251 kB]                                                                                                     
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3-minimal amd64 3.10.6-1~22.04 [24.3 kB]                                                                                                          
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 media-types all 7.0.0 [25.5 kB]                                                                                                                                 
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libmpdec3 amd64 2.5.1-2build2 [86.8 kB]                                                                                                                         
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 readline-common all 8.1.2-1 [53.5 kB]                                                                                                                           
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libreadline8 amd64 8.1.2-1 [153 kB]                                                                                                                             
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libsqlite3-0 amd64 3.37.2-2ubuntu0.1 [641 kB]                                                                                                           
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpython3.10-stdlib amd64 3.10.6-1~22.04.2 [1832 kB]                                                                                                  
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3.10 amd64 3.10.6-1~22.04.2 [497 kB]                                                                                                             
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpython3-stdlib amd64 3.10.6-1~22.04 [6910 B]                                                                                                        
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3 amd64 3.10.6-1~22.04 [22.8 kB]                                                                                                                 
Fetched 6494 kB in 14s (478 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                       
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package libpython3.10-minimal:amd64.
(Reading database ... 4395 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.6-1~22.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.6-1~22.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libexpat1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libexpat1_2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libexpat1:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3.10-minimal.
Preparing to unpack .../python3.10-minimal_3.10.6-1~22.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.10-minimal (3.10.6-1~22.04.2) ...
Setting up libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.6-1~22.04.2) ...
Setting up libexpat1:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up python3.10-minimal (3.10.6-1~22.04.2) ...
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.10/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-310.pyc.139849676216832'dpkg: error processing package python3.10-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3.10-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.10-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Looking into the `/user/lib/python3.10/__pychache__/` all of the files in the directory are `-rw-r--r--`

How can the install complain of Permission denied when running as root and the user permissions for every file in the directory is `rw`?

**Update**

I upgraded to docker 20.10.22 build 3a2c30b but still am encountering this issue.

Comment: I can install python2 (```apt install python2```) and that works.  But installing python3 still fails.

Comment: I'm really at a loss as to how to ask this question better.  The failure is so off the wall  and strange that I am having trouble believing anyone can actually reproduce it.

Comment: As you're asking this question, it seems to be more about using the APT package manager than actual programming, and another site like [ubuntu.se] might be a better place to ask.  Remember that anything you do in this shell is intrinsically temporary and will be lost as soon as the container exits; I might even say you should almost never try to install software inside a running container, and therefore directly running the `ubuntu` image isn't that useful.  [Docker's Python tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/) might be a better starting point.

Comment: It is if you are going to commit the container into another image.  I'm not sure Ask Ubuntu is exactly the right place for it ether.  There is a Docker tag that seems to be pretty active, so I figured it wouldn't be a bad place to post?

Comment: You should probably never ever use `docker commit`.  (How do you plan to rebuild the image when there's a mandatory critical security fix in a year?  How will you answer licensing requests?)

Comment: The environment we are working in is strictly version controlled.  If a new security fix or update is necessary, it will have to be approved.  So commit actually helps in that it fixes everything to a particular version/build.

Comment: This issue can't be reproduced with your info. Are you sure you are using fresh new Ubuntu image (as you are using docker commit)?
Checked in host Ubuntu 20.04.5 with docker 20.10.22 and fresh ubuntu:latest.

Comment: Thanks @ClaudioWeiler, yeah, I'm using a brand new ubuntu image and haven't done a commit yet as getting python3 to install is just not working.  Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Is your `id` output like this: `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`? On docker container.

Comment: Yes it is.  Here is the output:
$ docker run -ti ubuntu
root@464b30c70712:/# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

Comment: Here is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75651585/docker-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-command-returned-a-non

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From selected answer of the question noted above https://stackoverflow.com/a/75687477/1843507

---

I just had this problem on my Ubuntu system while installing python3.6.

I found [this discussion on the docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/bug-on-apt-install-permission-denied/100196/9), which basically states, that having installed docker as snap creates this problem. The discussion suggests, that snap and the storage driver overlay2 are not working correctly together.

I removed the docker snap via

```
sudo snap remove docker
```

and then followed the [official install guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) from Docker for Ubuntu systems. Note, that I did not select the desktop version, since that seems to do something weird with VMs, like it works on Windows. I selected the Ubuntu server guide, though I'm using it on my Ubuntu desktop.

The installation of packages via apt-get is now working correctly and without errors.

---

The alternative mentioned in the discussion - which I didn't try - is to set your Docker daemon to use vfs as storage driver. I'm copying the corresponding instructions from Paul Larsons post there:

- edit /var/snap/docker/current/config/daemon.json and replace “overlay2” with “vfs” for the storage-driver
- run sudo snap restart docker

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04 and this time did not select Docker as one of the packages installed along with Ubuntu.  I installed Docker manually after the Ubuntu install completed and after a reboot.

Now it works fine.

I reinstalled ubuntu 22.04 again, just to make sure I could reproduce the problem and indeed, if I select Docker to be installed with Ubuntu, the problem resurfaces.

Comment: Well done. Worth filing an issue on Ubuntu issue tracker directly then?

Comment: I would, but I'm not sure if my description is sufficient to have someone reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://forums.docker.com/t/bug-on-apt-install-permission-denied/100196/9 (referenced in @sami's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76045328/4016256) the problem is docker running as a snap and docker being configured with the (default) overlayfs storage driver.

You can change the driver and avoid the issue; the linked forum post suggests `vfs` with the following description:

> The vfs storage driver is intended for testing purposes, and for situations where no copy-on-write filesystem can be used. Performance of this storage driver is poor, and is not generally recommended for production use.

You can use the `btrfs` or `zfs` drivers instead.

- https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/
- https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/zfs-driver/

I've personally had success with the `btrfs` driver.

Docker's instructions state that `/var/lib/docker` must *be a* `btrfs` mount. But that is not strictly true `/var/lib/docker` must be *on a* `btrfs` filesystem (e.g. `/` or `/var` etc); for the snap installation of docker `/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker` is the storage root, so *that* will need to be *on a* `btrfs` filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

i had this same error but the answers i got were different, but finally making that same commands as a root user in docker, or you can try to look for enough permissions from the host system admin, otherwise your command will continue to fail, that possibly should solve your error