# Docker | PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied & command returned a non-zero code: 100

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, aws-cli

I have been working on a FastAI model and am now ready to deploy it. However, I'm facing difficulties in getting the model to work via Docker locally.

I'm at a loss as to what's causing the problem and how to resolve it. I've little experience with Docker. Creating my own Dockerfile is new to me; so I may have left out obvious commands.

`Dockerfile`:

```
# Install image and dependencies
FROM python:3.9

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the application files from the host to the container
COPY app.py /app/

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --fix-missing && \
    pip install pip==20.2

# Install project dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

# Download model artefacts from S3
RUN apt-get install -y awscli \
    && mkdir -p /models/ \
    && aws s3 cp s3://foo.pkl /models/ \
    && aws s3 cp s3://bar.pth /models/

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the application
CMD ["python", "/app/app.py"]

# docker run -p 8000:8000 my_image
```

Traceback:

```
Step 7/9 : RUN apt-get install -y awscli     && mkdir -p /models/     && aws s3 cp s3://foo/bar.pkl /models/     && aws s3 cp s3://foo/bar.pth /models/
 ---> Running in 7b2d18a2957a
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
...
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-39.pyc.140347841853312'
...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y awscli     && mkdir -p /models/     && aws s3 cp s3://foo.pkl /models/     && aws s3 cp s3://bar.pth /models/' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Many of these occur: `[Errno 13] Permission denied`

---

Inserting `user` before failing Step didn't work:

```
# Create a new user
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash user

# Give newuser all privileges
RUN usermod -aG sudo user

# Switch to user
USER user
```

Traceback:

```
Step 10/12 : RUN apt-get install -y awscli     && mkdir -p /models/     && aws s3 cp s3://foo.pkl /models/     && aws s3 cp s3://bar.pth /models/
 ---> Running in 96d1e6f73307
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y awscli     && mkdir -p /models/     && aws s3 cp s3://foo.pkl /models/     && aws s3 cp s3://bar.pth /models/' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just had this problem on my Ubuntu system while installing python3.6.

I found [this discussion on the docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/bug-on-apt-install-permission-denied/100196/9), which basically states, that having installed docker as snap creates this problem. The discussion suggests, that snap and the storage driver overlay2 are not working correctly together.

I removed the docker snap via

```
sudo snap remove docker
```

and then followed the [official install guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) from Docker for Ubuntu systems. Note, that I did not select the desktop version, since that seems to do something weird with VMs, like it works on Windows. I selected the Ubuntu server guide, though I'm using it on my Ubuntu desktop.

The installation of packages via apt-get is now working correctly and without errors.

---

The alternative mentioned in the discussion - which I didn't try - is to set your Docker daemon to use vfs as storage driver. I'm copying the corresponding instructions from Paul Larsons post there:

- edit /var/snap/docker/current/config/daemon.json and replace “overlay2” with “vfs” for the storage-driver
- run sudo snap restart docker

Comment: Hey, I'm back online now. Running this command seems to be taking ages for me. I opened a new Terminal: `$ sudo snap remove docker
[sudo] password for me: 
error: snap "docker" has "remove-snap" change in progress
` Will keep posted

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336399/what-does-snap-opera-has-remove-snap-change-in-progress-mean-and-how-do-i) suggests, that this means snap is currently doing something in the background and you need to wait, until that is finished. Also: You can add the --purge option to the snap remove, so that snap won't create a snapshot of the snap as backup (which can take a long time)

Comment: Terminal is hung at `$ docker run -p 8000:8000 my_image
15 Mar 2023 10:23:05,466 [INFO] (rapid) exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=)
` but is a separate issue

Comment: If you have many images, volumes etc, in your docker snap installation, consider to export data from there beforehand and then run `sudo snap remove --purge docker` to avoid that a larger snapshot is kept by snap in your filesystem.

Comment: Addition to the alternative answer by @chrisl, I had to also run `docker system prune -a` to get it running

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can add the USER command to your Dockerfile to switch to the root user before running the command that requires elevated privileges. Here is an example:

```
FROM ubuntu

# Switch to root user
USER root
RUN apt-get update

# Switch back to non-root user
USER nonrootuser
```

Or you can add the "sudo" with your commands like "sudo apt-get update"