# Permission denied while building a container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, permission-denied, docker-build

I am trying to build a image with a Dockerfile here :

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y postfix

CMD ["postfix", "-a"]
```

But when I try to run the command `docker run . -t postfix` the build stop at the **RUN**
keyword `RUN apt-get install -y postfix` with an error of permission :

```
Preparing to unpack .../python3.10-minimal_3.10.6-1~22.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.10-minimal (3.10.6-1~22.04.2) ...
Setting up libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.6-1~22.04.2) ...
Setting up libexpat1:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up python3.10-minimal (3.10.6-1~22.04.2) ...
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.10/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-310.pyc.140681824950784'dpkg: error processing package python3.10-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3.10-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.10-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y postfix' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I tried to run the docker build with sudo, but the same error comes.
Also, my user who builds the container is in the docker group.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you elaborate more so i can help

Comment: @ayushjain Yes of course. I am trying to create a container for the Postfix service. So in my image I want to install it (of course the Dockerfile isn't finished ye, but I begin with a little one and add after the it works)

Comment: @ayushjain Okay, I will take a screenshot

Comment: Tried it on my computer (Podman, instead of Docker) using your `debian:10.8` example and did not face the same problem. I see some of your steps are using the cache - have you tried to run this with `docker build --no-cache`? Sometimes this fixes issues if the package has been updated and the cache is using an old layer for the `apt update` step.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  It looks like you already included the Dockerfile in plain text; if the extended error logs are helpful then [edit] the question to include more text, but there's no reason to include the same data as hard-to-read PNG files.

Comment: [Docker | PermissionError: Errno 13 Permission denied & command returned a non-zero code: 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75651585/docker-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-command-returned-a-non) suggests you might hit this problem if you installed Docker using the `snap` tool on a native-Linux host; does this match your setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze I tested to build this Dockerfile with another Virtual Machine and it worked, so it could be that